# Export large number of rows from SQL Server 2012 to Excel

Tags: c#, sql-server, excel

I realize this is a well covered topic, but after looking at a number of posts am looking for a different solution. The application is a c# web, .net framework 4.5 application and is required to export around 80,000+ rows from a SQL Server 2012 database to an Excel Spreadsheet Template (to make it look pretty and do formatting) and stream it to a user for download.

I realize one answer might be to re-ask why we need to do this and find an alternative way. The application is looking at financial transactions which are numerous. The users want to retain the ability to export and play with the data in Excel. Before I start looking into alternative ways of helping them I want to see if anyone has any bright ideas!

The current solution loops through the data and generates XML using the OpenXML library. Whilst this works well and quickly for smaller datasets this is taking a very long time for larger datasets.

Are there any alternatives to creating Excel files, without:

1. extracting all data from the database into the application via some sort of data transfer object which is slow as its transferring a lot of data around.
2. using third party components requiring licensing, as there is no budget.
3. using OpenXml to loop through all the rows and generate the full output.
4. generating and storing a physical file on a network drive as there are data security restrictions.
5. using SSRS

I'm thinking something along the lines of using SQL Server to generate the Excel file in memory (via SSIS), opening a stream from the application, editing the formatting via OpenXml or something else and then streaming the file to the user. Unsure if this is possible or if there are other options?

Answer (score 2):

You can try this approach but, of course involves extracting data from the database to the application.

```
Response.Clear();
Response.Buffer = true;
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=YourFileName.xls");
Response.Charset = "";
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
{
    HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);

    FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(Server.MapPath("~/App_Themes/YourCSS.css"));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    StreamReader sr = fi.OpenText();
    while (sr.Peek() >= 0)
        sb.Append(sr.ReadLine());
    sr.Close();

    sb.Append(" table.tnew tr { height: 20px; } ");
    sb.Append(" table.tnew tr td, th { border:1px solid #CCCCCC; } ");
    sb.Append(" table.tnew tr.RowTotale td { background-color:#F5F5F5; color: #333333; text-transform:uppercase; font-weight: bold; font-size:11px; } ");

    GridView gv = new GridView();
    gv.DataSource = YourDataSource;
    gv.DataBind();
    gv.RenderControl(hw);

    Response.Output.Write(string.Format("<html><head><style type='text/css'>{0}</style></head><body>{1}</body></html>", sb.ToString(), sw.ToString());
    Response.Flush();
    Response.End();
}
```

As you can see, you can even add your CSS file and additional styling.

Comment: i haven't seen that method of styling response output before so +1, but as mentioned, pulling the data into the application to render will slow it down unfortunately so -1.

Comment: @sarin what's the amount of data (in bytes)?

Comment: Well the generated excel file with the 80000 rows using OpenXML is around 10MB at the moment.

Comment: @sarin but what about the data from the database?

Comment: Not sure this is the best way but followed this post to get data size (http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/25531/how-can-i-get-the-actual-data-size-per-row-in-a-sql-server-table ). It came out at 13301442 bytes or 13.3 MB.

Comment: @sarin well, you'd better do it using SSIS then.